# Is __attribute__ required in implementation?

Tags: objective-c, clang

Using [__attribute__](http://nshipster.com/__attribute__/) is a neat way to hint certain properties of your method to the compiler.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (NSString *)someString __attribute__((pure));
@end
@implementation
- (NSString *)someString __attribute__((pure)) {
  return @"Hello";
}
@end
```

Removing the `__attribute__` in the implementation doesn't cause a build warning (though it has in previous versions of Xcode, I believe. If it's not marked there, but is marked in the header, does the compiler find the attribute in all cases? Is it better practice to include it in the implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most important that it be marked in the header, actually. The utility of pure functions is in the compiler not having to re-read nonlocal memory after the function's return; that is, it's a hint to code *using* the function, not the function itself.

Comment: I doesn't make sense in the implementation... You're right about the memory read stuff, and that's precisely why it makes only sense in the header, since it affects code that uses the function, meaning the compiler will be able to optimise the calls... Repeating the attribute in the implementation is simply not useful, since the function is already marked.

Comment: That makes sense. Where I'm still struggling is methods that aren't declared in the header (ie, private-ish methods). I'm assuming you'd put the attribute on their actual declarations in the implementation? Seems like you have an opportunity to lose the attribute if a public method goes private (delete from header and forget to move attribute), so I wonder what the best practice is.

Comment: Even when using private categories or class extensions, you should declare your selectors in an interface...

Comment: What I meant was if a public method became a private method (not in a category or extension, just for use internal to the class), so that it didn't need to be known outside the `.m`, but now I can't think of any legitimate case where that would happen.

Comment: Then you should probably try to compile your code with "-Wundeclared-selector".